# Javascript Object loses state despite staying in scope

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a simple Javascript program that is meant to scroll through a list of text items over a specified time per item. Most of the code is working, but I'm having trouble with my objects not retaining state.

I've got a BuildManager object that loads a build (a set of instructions), then re-assembles an array of time delta's and DOM objects. Later on, a click function from a button can refer to an instance of this object, thus examining its current build. The BuildManager instance is building the array just fine, but when the function called by the button runs, the BuildManager instance says that its array has zero length. I know it's a problem with scope or something similar, but I just can't find where. During testing, I noticed that if I make the array global instead of an object property, then it works, as the global variable retains the modifications.

**TLDR:**
The document.ready function creates a Build Manager called manager, and sets up listeners. I click the #load-build-button, which successfully creates the array in manager (verified). Later I click the #start-build-button, which fails because when it calls manager.getNextStepStartingTime(), the managers active_build has length 0.

Here's the code reduced to what's necessary:

```
var BuildManager = function() {
    var current_array = [
        [5, "This is the step with the number: 1"],
        [10, "This is the step with the number: 2"],
        [15, "This is the step with the number: 3"],
        [25, "This is the step with the number: 4"],
        [40, "This is the step with the number: 5"],
        [45, "This is the step with the numberasdfadsfasdfasf: 6"],
        [47, "This is the step with the number: 7"],
        [49, "This is the step with the number: 8"],
        [50, "This is the step with the number: 9"],
        [60, "This is the step with the number: 10"],
        [120, "This is the step with the number: 11"],
        [130, "This is the step with the number: 13"],
        [133, "This is the step with the number: 14"],
        [135, "This is the step with the numbasdfasdfadsfasfder: 15"],
        [137, "This is the step with the number: 16"],
        [139, "This is the step with the number: 17"],
        [145, "This is the step with the number: 18"]
    ];

    this.active_build = [];

    this.loadBuild = function() {
        $(".build-item").remove();
        this.active_build = [];
        for (var i = 0, len = current_array.length; i < len; i++) {
            $(".build-list").append("<div class='build-item'>" + current_array[i][1] + "</div>\n");
            this.active_build.push([current_array[i][0], $(".build-item:contains('"+ current_array[i][1] +"')")]);
        }
    };

    this.getNextStepStartTime = function() {
        return this.active_build[0][0];
    };

    this.getNextStepHeight = function() {
        return this.active_build[0][1].height;
    };

    this.completeStep = function() {
        this.active_build.shift();
    };
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    /* Initialize Jquery items */
    $("input[type=button]").button();

    /* High level data because setInterval doesn't work with objects */
    var total_time_passed = 0;
    var manager = new BuildManager();

    function timerFunction() {
        /* If this isn't the first time here, we've just completed a step, so let the manager know */
        if (total_time_passed > 0) {
            manager.completeStep();
        }

        /* Find out how long until the next step is complete, and animate to it */
        var time_to_next = manager.getNextStepStartTime()-total_time_passed;
        if (time_to_next > 0) {
            var build_list = $(".build-list");
            var prev_pos = parseInt(build_list.css("margin-top"));
            build_list.animate({marginTop: prev_pos - manager.getNextStepHeight()}, time_to_next*1000);
        }

        /* Set this function to run again once the target time has been reached */
        total_time_passed += time_to_next;
        setTimeout(timerFunction, time_to_next*1000);
    }

    function startBuild() {
        timerFunction();
    }

    function stopBuild() {
        //does nothing yet
    }

    /* Setup Click Handlers */
    $("#load-build-button").click(manager.loadBuild);
    $("#start-build-button").click(startBuild);
    $("#stop-build-button").click(stopBuild);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`manager.loadBuild` is a reference to a function which carries no information about `manager`. You need to pass a reference to a function bound to your scope:

```
$("#load-build-button").click(manager.loadBuild.bind(manager));
```

Alternatively, you could bind the functions when you declare them:

```
this.loadBuild = function() {
    $(".build-item").remove();
    this.active_build = [];
    for (var i = 0, len = current_array.length; i < len; i++) {
        $(".build-list").append("<div class='build-item'>" + current_array[i][1] + "</div>\n");
        this.active_build.push([current_array[i][0], $(".build-item:contains('"+ current_array[i][1] +"')")]);
    }
}.bind(this); // bound!
```

Comment: Thanks, that resolved it. Is either method preferred?

Comment: The more commonly used is the first i think, but the second seems cleaner to me.